# Is alias::Class any different from alias.Class?

Tags: c#, alias

I've been reading some "hidden C# features" stuff and there are posts from 2011 about this:

```
using web = System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using win = System.Windows.Forms;

web::Control aWebControl = new web::Control();
win::Control aFormControl = new win::Control();
```

And all along I've been using it like so:

```
using xna = Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using sd = System.Drawing;

var rect = new xna.Rectangle();
var bounds = new sd.Rectangle();
```

Is there any significant difference between using `::` and `.` operators on aliases? Is there something you can (not) do with only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two differences (IIRC).

The first difference is that `::` can only be used with aliases.

The only other *real* difference is that `::` can be used to access the `global` namespace, since it is implicitly aliased.

So this won't work:

```
System::Int32 myInt = 0;
```

But this (albeit, pointless example) will work:

```
using System = global::System;

System::Int32 myInt = 0;
```